# Access angular $scope without element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Every answer I have found involves using an element and accessing `$scope` from there.

I want to access scope for a given controller, preferably by controller name, in javascript outside the controller definition. Is this even possible?

---

For clarity, I'm trying to update a variable being watched on `$scope` within the controller. I want to have one standalone function that I can pass some parameters into that can perform this function for a multitude of controllers in my application.

If I'm going about this completely the wrong way please correct me. Just started getting in to angular recently.

---

Something like:

```
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);

myapp.controller("myController1", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.specialVar = "some value";
});
myapp.controller("myController2", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.specialVar = "some other value";
});

var myFunction = function(controller, val){
    //set the value of specialVar for the passed controller to the passed value
    myapp.AccessController(controller).$scope('specialVar', val);
}
```

Comment: use a service to share and store and bind data. Not 100% clear what you are trying to do though...or what higher level problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @charlietfl added an example

Comment: so where were you intending on using that function? inside the app? If so you definitely would use a service

Comment: @charlietfl yes

Comment: do some reading up on services and sharing data then. Will find lots of articles/tutorials examples etc in web search

Comment: I don't think you can do this unless there is a parent-child or sibling relationship between the Controllers, and they both are directives. If those things are true, you can use the ^require syntax. But I'm with @charlietfl. What is the end goal of this (not what have you decided the solution is, but what is the problem you think it is the solution to).

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I want to update values inside the controller (so that they appear in the dom), sometimes from user actions elsewhere in the app, sometimes from data from an async call. I was hoping to create one function I could reuse rather than call a separate function in each controller.

Comment: @RandyHall Accessing `$scope` outside a controller is really an anti-pattern in AngularJS. In saying that, if you need to have some shared method that updated `$scope`, you could have a service method like:
`service.updateScope = function(scope) { ... }`, and then invoke it in your controller `service.updateScope($scope)`. Again, I'd recommend against this.

Comment: i don't remind if it works but it may work: update the $rootScope, it should update all the $scopes of all the controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that you can have any number of instances of a given controller coexisting in your application, but only one service; services are effectively singleton. If you're able to assume that there's only ever exactly one instance of a given controller, then it sounds like you're treating that controller as a service, and that you should just use the service instead. If you're *not* able to assume that there's only ever exactly one instance, then you absolutely need to access through `angular.element(domElement).scope()`, because otherwise you're going to have a hard time selecting which of the many instances you're talking about.

Remember, you can always use a service and a dictionary/object to map from an arbitrary key into a given scope, if you'd rather not use the element to look up the scope.